# Formato adecuado para implementar videos en Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

En algunos dispositivos como Sansung S5, y algunos dispositivos específicos, el video que puse de splashscreen no se muestra. El dispositivo dice: "No se puede reproducir este video". El video esta en formato .mp4

El Logcat me dice que tengo el siguiente error:

E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147479527)
E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -38)
D/VideoView: Error: 1,-2147479527

¿Cuál es la forma adecuada de implementar imagenes y videos en Android Studio para que TODOS los dispositivos los muestre?

No sé si tenga algo que ver pero el video que intento reproducir, que se llama "intro", pesa 4.40Mb y mide 1400 x 2440

Es cierto que si pongo muchos comentarios o dejo espacios entre las líneas del código, hago que se carge la RAM y no funcione bien la Activity?

Gracias.

//ARCHIVO JAVA:

```
package com.hem.personal.hem;

import android.content.Context; import android.content.Intent; import 
android.content.SharedPreferences; import android.media.MediaPlayer; import 
android.net.Uri; import android.os.Bundle; import 
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; import android.util.Log; import 
android.view.WindowManager; import android.widget.VideoView; import 
com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics; import io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric;

public class splashscreen extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
//ESCONDE EL STATUS BAR
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
//ESCONDE EL STATUS BAR
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);
getSupportActionBar().hide();
videoView = findViewById(R.id.videoView);
Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + 
R.raw.intro);
videoView.setVideoURI(video);
videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener()
{
@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer)
{ if (isFinishing())
return;
}
});

videoView.start();

}}
```

// ARCHIVO XML:

```
<VideoView
android:id="@+id/videoView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
```

Comment: Cristina, como curiosidad que extensión tiene tu archivo de video y de donde lo obtuviste?

Comment: La extensión del vídeo es .mp4 y lo hice en After effects

Answer (score 1):

Los mensajes de error que muestras se deben a que el formato de tus videos no es reproducible debido a que se usaron codecs que no son soportados por android:

> No se puede reproducir este video E/MediaPlayer: error (1,
>   -2147479527) E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -38) D/VideoView: Error: 1,-2147479527

Generalmente puedo mencionarte que los codecs soportados son :

> - AAC para audio.
> - H.263 / H.264 para video.

Estos serían los codecs y formatos soportados por android:

**https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats#audio-codecs**